# как в коде нарисовать рамку вокруг ListView?

Tags: android, android-studio, listview

сейчас делаю так

```
ListView lv = new ListView(this);
ShapeDrawable drawable = new ShapeDrawable();
drawable.getPaint().setColor(Color.BLACK);
drawable.getPaint().setStrokeWidth(5);
lv.setBackground(drawable);
```

но рамки нет, заливает весь Background черным и все.

Подскажите пожалуйста что не так?

Comment: устанавливаешь контейнеру, в котором этот ListView фоном цвет, который нужен рамке и ставишь в этом контейнере маржины в нужную толщину рамки

Comment: спасибоб но так не пойдет , контейнер прозрачный, нужна рамка

Comment: ListView должен остаться прозрачным, он не должен закрывать изображение за ним.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 Вариант - через xml-атрибуты:

Для ListView делаем прозрачный бэкграунд с рамкой- *res/drawable/back.xml*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#FF000000" />
</shape>
```

толщина рамки - 2dp, цвет - черный

назначаем этот бэкграунд списку:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/back" />
</FrameLayout>
```

2 Вариант - тоже самое через код:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ListView lv = findViewById(R.id.list);
        GradientDrawable drawable = new GradientDrawable();
        drawable.setStroke(2, Color.BLACK);
        lv.setBackground(drawable);
}
```

результат:

[image: screen]

фон контейнера - зеленый. Список имеет прозрачный фон с черной рамкой.

Comment: Недавно столкнулся: на некоторых аппаратах `shape` заливается чёрным, если не задавать заливку явно (например прозрачным: `<solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />`)

Comment: спасибо большое.